# Yii2: Add new text field on clicking add button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I want to create text fields in my form so that when i click on `Add New Field` button it should open a new next field.
here is my code for form:

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'status_type')->textInput(['maxlength' => 
true]) ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 
'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn 
btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

what should i add in the code to achieve this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution as follows:
**Js file**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.my-form .add-items').click(function(){
        var n = $('.text-items').length + 1;
        var box_html = $('<p class="text-items"><label for="item' + n + '">Item <span class="items-number">' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[]" value="" id="item' + n + '" /> <a href="#" class="remove-items">Remove</a></p>');
        box_html.hide();
        $('.my-form p.text-items:last').after(box_html);
        box_html.fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });

    $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-items', function(){
    //$(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
    if($('.text-items').length > 1){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $('.items-number').each(function(index){
                $(this).text( index + 1 );
            });
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

**View**

```
<div class="my-form">

    <?php
    if( !$model->isNewRecord){
        $items = StatusType::find()->where(['status_id'=>$model->id])->orderBy('order')->all();
        if(!empty($items)){
        foreach ($items as $item) {
    ?>

        <p class="text-items">
            <label for="item<?= $item->order ?>">Item <span class="items-number"><?= $item->order ?></span></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="items[]" value="<?= $item->title ?>" id="item<?= $item->order ?>" /><br>
            <a href="#" class="remove-items">Remove</a>
        </p>
     <?php }}else{
     ?>
        <p class="text-items">
            <label for="item">Item <span class="items-number">1</span></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="items[]" value="" id="item" /><br>
            <a href="#" class="remove-items">Remove</a>
        </p>

     <?php  
        } } else{?>
        <p class="text-items">
            <label for="item">Item <span class="items-number">1</span></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="items[]" value="" id="item" /><br>
            <a href="#" class="remove-items">Remove</a>
        </p>
     <?php }?>
    <?= Html::button('Add More', ['class'=>'glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn btn-default btn-sm add-items']) ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cant understand your question clearly, but if you want to add dinamic form in your app, try Look at this first, if this url cant solve your problem, come back and we will discuss how to solve your problem. . .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqFpTBr323Y